# How can I make the border hide behind the h3 in this example?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/fjZfL/31/

I really want the "who" part to be in front of it, you know? I tried using a z-index, but to no avail.

Comment: It *is* in front of it, but they're both black, so you can't tell. Did you mean to give it a background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear behind the h3. For instance, change the colour of the paragraph's border to red and make it 5px and you will see that it goes behind the black letters.